# Qual a diferença em usar transition: all e transition: [propriedade específica]?

Tags: css, css-transições

Fazendo uma animação simples em CSS para aumentar o `height` de uma `div` usando `transition: all` e surgiu-me uma dúvida. Veja o exemplo:

```css
div{
   width: 100px;
   height: 30px;
   background: red;
   transition: all 1s ease;
}

div:hover{
   height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>Passe o mouse</div>
```

Eu poderia usar `transition: height`, já que eu quero apenas aplicar a transição no `height`, mas também usando o `all` o resultado é o mesmo, já que o `all` irá aplicar o efeito a qualquer propriedade alterada (desde que a propriedade tenha suporte para tal).

Então, não é melhor sempre usar o `all` já que pega todas as propriedades? Usar `all` implica em alguma desvantagem em relação a usar uma propriedade específica no `transition` (como `height`, `width`, `background-color` etc.)? Caso isso seja indiferente, porque não se usa apenas o `all` em qualquer caso?

Comment: Além de performance, pode ser que o programador queira que o efeito seja ser aplicado a certas propriedades e não a todas, ou então aplicar efeitos diferentes a propriedades diferentes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara o grande problema ai é a performance. Usar o `transition:all` consome muito recurso do browser, pois ele vai "tentar" animar todos os estilos da classe, mesmo que eles não tenham animação, isso deixa o browser esperando por algo que não vai acontecer e acaba custando caro pro desempenho do browser, ainda mais se vc usar isso em todo seu css.

Outro ponto é que como o `transition:all` sua animação em sim perde o desempenho, ela pode perder a fluidez e fica "pulando passos", como se perde FPSs na transição.

Quando vc tiver que animar mais de uma coisa com o `transition` vc pode fazer dessa forma.

```css
div{
   width: 100px;
   height: 30px;
   background: red;
   transition: height 1s ease, background 1s ease;
}

div:hover{
   height: 100px;
   background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>Passe o mouse</div>
```

Então no geral o recomendado é **não** usar o `transition:all`

**Dica:** Vc pode adicionar no seu elemento `transform:translateZ(0)` para ativa a aceleração por hardware via GPU quando for animar o elemento, isso tb funciona para animações com `@keyframes`. Se for do seu interesse procure também sobre a propriedade `will-change`, mas essa só vale a penas se for usar junto com JS, pois vc precisa adicionar e remover antes e depois da animação para não ficar consumindo recurso do browser sem estar com a animação ativada.

Comment: Boa! Era isso mesmo o que eu queria saber.

Comment: @dvd tem uma resposta no StackOverflow que tb trata disso, eu já tinha lido antes, mas não achei a referência agora para tem passar. O Chrome por exemplo consome memória pra caramba, então tudo para evitar esse consumo já é valido, principalmente no Mobile

Comment: Hugo, deixa eu tirar uma dúvida rápida com vc: se eu tiver um site com apenas a index, tipo uma hotpage, é melhor eu fazer o CSS todo no <style></style> mesmo ou é sempre bom usar um .css externo?

Comment: @dvd eu estou justamente trabalhando em um projeto desse tipo, uma pagina singlepage, vou te dar uma opinião pessoal, vou deixar o .css do pro desenvolvimento, como vai ser uma página estática no final vou compilar tudo junto inclusive os svg, só os js que vou chamar por requisição

Comment: @dvd ontem escrevi rápido pelo celular, mas ao terminar o projeto, vou colocar todo o css minificado dentro da tag style. O problema é que o projeto usa Bootstrap4 esse vai ser o único .css que vou chamar indexado na head, o resto vai tudo no `<style>`